# Run local GCC on remote linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, make, gcc

I'm sure this has been asked before but after some time searching I'm not finding quite what I want.

I have a test server that I cannot install GCC or other development needs on. On my development linux computer I can ssh to the test server, I want to install certain packages that require running ./configure and make.

Is there a way to run the make processes on my computer pointed at the remote host to install that way?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't install locally to a temp dir, create a tarball, and copy remotely? In effect, you'd be doing this, but in harder ways.

Comment: I assume if I run configure and make on my local machine, then it will mess up the current install of applications I'm trying to install, and what I'm developing - or does it only affect things when I call Make Install?

Comment: I need to run make install on the remote computer is the issue, not just make

Comment: @FaultyJuggler You should not mess up your system as long as you don't do `make install`. `./configure` and `make` only operate in the current directory (unless the developer did something crazy, but I've never seen that).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would probably be to use sshfs to mount the remote directories on the appropriate locations on your development system and then run the build processes there.